# How to cbind a discrete factor to a large matrix

Tags: r, matrix, cbind

I have a discrete factor, of length 79.

```
[1] 4 6 6 4 6 1 6 4 1 6 1 4 6 1 1 1 6 6 6 6 6 4 1 6 6 4 6 6 1 1 6 4 6 1 6 6 4 4
[39] 6 6 4 1 1 4 1 1 6 1 1 6 6 1 1 6 4 1 1 6 1 6 6 1 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 6 1 1 1 1 1
[77] 6 6 1
Levels: 1 4 6
```

I am trying to cbind this discrete factor to a large matrix with dimensions: 79 rows by 1921 columns. I am told that my end result should be the original matrix with columns added to it, but I'm not sure how I should approach this problem. Thanks in advance.

This is the code I was given to cbind the factor to the matrix:

```
dd1 = mat.x
for(v in levels(X)){
    nv = rep(0, length(X))
    nv[X==v] = 1
    dd1 = cbind(dd1, nv)
}
```

I get this warning message:

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In cbind(dd1, nv) :
>
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
>
> 2: In cbind(dd1, nv) :
>
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
>
> 3: In cbind(dd1, nv) :
>
> number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Comment: No-can-do with a matrix.  Perhaps a data frame? Matrix columns must all be the same `class`

Comment: Did you actually try `cbind` or not? I don't see why `mat <- cbind(mat, vec)` shouldn't work (where `mat` is your matrix and `vec` is your factor vector)

Comment: That would work, but the factored vector will no longer be factored

Comment: Hi, I edited my original post to include warning message and code that I ran.

Comment: Did you confirm `length(X)==nrow(mat.x)`?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, it returned TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem was just a typo. Using the sample data

```
mat.x <- matrix(1, nrow=17, ncol=4)
X <- factor(sample(c(4,6,10), 17, replace=T))
```

this code worked

```
dd1 = mat.x
for(v in levels(X)){
    nv = rep(0, length(X))
    nv[X==v] = 1
    dd1 = cbind(dd1, nv)
}
```

Note that I had to change `nv[y==v] = 1` to `nv[X==v] = 1` because you did not define `y` anywhere in your problem.

Comment: wouldn't it be better/more efficient to use `cbind(mat.x,model.matrix(~X-1))` ?

Comment: Sure. I guess I was just trying to figure out why the code wasn't working.

Comment: Holy moly, you're right! I'm kicking myself right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

all elements in a  `matrix` must be the same class.   use data.frame or data.table instead

```
 data.frame(vec, mat)
```